# Change Menu Color for Selected Button (Using Ant Design with React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, menu, antd

Hello i'am writing to inquire about the process for changing the menu associated with a selected button. I am currently using Ant Design (antd) with React and would like to update the options displayed when the button is clicked.

Could you please provide guidance on how to modify the menu content for the selected button within the Ant Design framework? Any instructions or assistance you can offer would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your attention to this matter. I look forward to your response.

Sincerely

**React code:**

```
import BreadcumbCustom from 'views/share/BreadcumbCustom.jsx'
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import { AppstoreOutlined, MailOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons'
import { Menu } from 'antd'

const items = [
  {
    label: 'Tracciati',
    key: '1-1',
    icon: <MailOutlined />,
  },
  {
    label: 'Classificazioni',
    key: '1-2',
    icon: <AppstoreOutlined />,
  },
]
export default function MenuConfigurazioni() {
  const navigate = useNavigate()
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState()
  const handleDropdownItemClick = (e) => {
    setCurrent(e.key)
    if (e.key === '1-1') {
      navigate('/admin/configurazione')
    } else {
      navigate('/admin/configurazione/classificazioni')
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <BreadcumbCustom title={'Configurazione'} />
      <Menu
        onClick={handleDropdownItemClick}
        selectedKeys={[current]}
        mode='horizontal'
        items={items}
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve this

1. You can use CSS like this, [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-aj4am2?file=index.css)

```css
    .custom-menu .ant-menu-item-selected,
    .custom-menu .ant-menu-submenu-selected,
    .ant-menu-item-selected {
      color: "red !important";
    }
```

2. Otherwise you can use the `ConfigProvider` and `itemSelectedColor` [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hxpbpr?file=demo.tsx)

```js
<ConfigProvider
  theme={{
    components: {
      Menu: { itemSelectedColor: '#c22525 !important' },
    },
  }}
>
  <Space>
    <Menu
      className="custom-menu"
      onClick={onClick}
      selectedKeys={[current]}
      mode="horizontal"
      items={items}
    />
  </Space>
</ConfigProvider>
```

[image]
[Other menu design tokens](https://ant.design/components/menu#design-token)

Comment: my question is how change color

Comment: how can change blue color?

Comment: do you want to change background ?

Comment: no blue line ... near text

Comment: you can use horizontalItemSelectedColor property please check https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hxpbpr?file=demo.tsx